# Legend on second frame has only one entry, labeled wrong

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, legend

Using pgfplots in beamer with `\only` frames, the legend for the second frame (only) inexplicably shows only one entry, with the color of the last `\addlegendentry`, but the legend of the first. The other frames are fine.

(Note: my version of PGFplots is old, but when I try to update, I get an unrelated error about a missing number treated as zero on the blank line near the start of the file. The commit in pgfplots I used to generate these examples is b32c2a92a257, and the next commit, 6a9ee731a433, and evidently all newer ones, has the unrelated error.)

[image: First frame - OK]
[image: Second frame - bad]
[image: Third frame - OK]
[image: Fourth frame - OK]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Pgfplots problem with legend on second frame}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      %%\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(1.02,1.0)}, anchor=north west}}
      \begin{axis}[ xlabel={x}, ylabel={y},
        xmin=-1, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=2, width=8cm]
        \only<1>{
          \addplot[color=green,very thick,mark=none] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.2072) (-0.9900, 0.2550) (-0.9800, 0.3108) (-0.9700, 0.3751) (-0.9600, 0.4480)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0631) ( 0.9600, 0.0816) ( 0.9700, 0.1046) ( 0.9800, 0.1327) ( 0.9900, 0.1666)
          };
          \addlegendentry{green}
          \addplot[color=blue,very thick,mark=none] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.8885) (-0.9900, 0.8380) (-0.9800, 0.7513) (-0.9700, 0.6403) (-0.9600, 0.5188)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0003) ( 0.9600, 0.0001) ( 0.9700, 0.0000) ( 0.9800, 0.0000) ( 0.9900, 0.0000)
          };
          \addlegendentry{blue}
          \addplot[color=red,very thick,mark=none] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.1841) (-0.9900, 0.2137) (-0.9800, 0.2335) (-0.9700, 0.2402) (-0.9600, 0.2325)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0000) ( 0.9600, 0.0000) ( 0.9700, 0.0000) ( 0.9800, 0.0000) ( 0.9900, 0.0000)
          };
          \addlegendentry{red}
        }
        \only<2>{
          \addplot[color=green,very thick,mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.0011) (-0.9900, 0.0017) (-0.9800, 0.0024) (-0.9700, 0.0035) (-0.9600, 0.0049)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0001) ( 0.9600, 0.0002) ( 0.9700, 0.0003) ( 0.9800, 0.0005) ( 0.9900, 0.0008)
          };
          \addlegendentry{green}
          \addplot[color=blue,very thick,mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.4644) (-0.9900, 0.3446) (-0.9800, 0.2430) (-0.9700, 0.1630) (-0.9600, 0.1039)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0000) ( 0.9600, 0.0000) ( 0.9700, 0.0000) ( 0.9800, 0.0001) ( 0.9900, 0.0003)
          };
          \addlegendentry{blue}
          \addplot[color=red,very thick,mark=none] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.0005) (-0.9900, 0.0006) (-0.9800, 0.0006) (-0.9700, 0.0006) (-0.9600, 0.0005)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0000) ( 0.9600, 0.0000) ( 0.9700, 0.0000) ( 0.9800, 0.0000) ( 0.9900, 0.0000)
          };
          \addlegendentry{red}
        }
        \only<3>{
          \addplot[color=green,very thick,mark=none] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.0099) (-0.9900, 0.0136) (-0.9800, 0.0186) (-0.9700, 0.0251) (-0.9600, 0.0336)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0017) ( 0.9600, 0.0025) ( 0.9700, 0.0036) ( 0.9800, 0.0050) ( 0.9900, 0.0071)
          };
          \addlegendentry{green}
          \addplot[color=blue,very thick,mark=none] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.1346) (-0.9900, 0.0837) (-0.9800, 0.0495) (-0.9700, 0.0278) (-0.9600, 0.0149)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0002) ( 0.9600, 0.0005) ( 0.9700, 0.0012) ( 0.9800, 0.0026) ( 0.9900, 0.0054)
          };
          \addlegendentry{blue}
          \addplot[color=red,very thick,mark=none] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.0013) (-0.9900, 0.0011) (-0.9800, 0.0009) (-0.9700, 0.0007) (-0.9600, 0.0005)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0000) ( 0.9600, 0.0000) ( 0.9700, 0.0000) ( 0.9800, 0.0000) ( 0.9900, 0.0000)
          };
          \addlegendentry{red}
        }
        \only<4>{
          \addplot[color=green,very thick,mark=none] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.0131) (-0.9900, 0.0179) (-0.9800, 0.0243) (-0.9700, 0.0325) (-0.9600, 0.0431)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0024) ( 0.9600, 0.0034) ( 0.9700, 0.0049) ( 0.9800, 0.0068) ( 0.9900, 0.0095)
          };
          \addlegendentry{green}
          \addplot[color=blue,very thick,mark=none] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.2304) (-0.9900, 0.1530) (-0.9800, 0.0966) (-0.9700, 0.0580) (-0.9600, 0.0331)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0001) ( 0.9600, 0.0001) ( 0.9700, 0.0004) ( 0.9800, 0.0009) ( 0.9900, 0.0020)
          };
          \addlegendentry{blue}
          \addplot[color=red,very thick,mark=none] coordinates {
            (-1.0000, 0.0030) (-0.9900, 0.0027) (-0.9800, 0.0023) (-0.9700, 0.0019) (-0.9600, 0.0014)
            ( 0.9500, 0.0000) ( 0.9600, 0.0000) ( 0.9700, 0.0000) ( 0.9800, 0.0000) ( 0.9900, 0.0000)
          };
          \addlegendentry{red}
        }
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That happens because of the `forget plot` you put in the `\addplot` options in the second frame (that's exactly what that key is for). Remove those keys and it works. By the way, your code compiles without an error using the current PGFPlots version 1.8.

Comment: @Jake You are right, if I remove the `forget plot` it looks right. I have no idea why that command was originally put in. (Meta: not sure how to accept a comment as an answer.)

Comment: @Jake an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `forget plot` key from the two plots in the second frame. `forget plot` causes plots not to be shown in the legend.